# Arrange data in HTML table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, html-table

I have a below-mentioned dataframe:

DF (dput):

```
structure(list(ID = c("P-1", " P-1", 
    "P-1", "P-2", "P-3", "P-4", 
    "P-5", "P-6", "P-7", "P-8"
    ), Date = c("2020-03-16 12:11:33", "2020-03-16 13:16:04", 
    "2020-03-16 06:13:55", "2020-03-16 10:03:43", "2020-03-16 12:37:09", 
    "2020-03-16 06:40:24", "2020-03-16 09:46:45", "2020-03-16 12:07:44", 
    "2020-03-16 14:09:51", "2020-03-16 09:19:23"), Status = c("SA", 
    "SA", "SA", "RE", "RE", "RE", 
    "RE", "XA", "XA", "XA"), Flag2 = c("L", 
    "L","L", NA, "K", "J", NA, NA, "H", "G"), Value = c(5929.81, 
    5929.81, 5929.81, NA, 6969.33, 740.08, NA, NA, 1524.8, NA), Flag2 = c("CL", 
    "CL", "CL", NA, "RY", "", NA, NA, "", NA), Flag3 = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, "RI", "PO", NA, "SS", "DDP", NA)), .Names = c("ID", 
    "Date", "Status", "Flag", "Value", 
    "Flag2", "Flag3"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am using below-mentioned code:

```
    df %>% mutate(L = ifelse(Flag == "L",1,0),
                  K = ifelse(Flag == "K",1,0),
                  # etc for Flag) %>%
      mutate(sub_status = NA) %>%
      mutate(sub_status = ifelse(!is.na(Flag2) & Flag3 == 0, "a", sub_status),
             sub_status = ifelse(is.na(Flag2) & Flag3 != 0, "b", sub_status),
             # etc for sub-status) %>%
      mutate(value_class = ifelse(0 <= Value & Value <= 15000, "0-15000", "15000-50000")) %>%
      group_by(Date, status, sub_status, value_class) %>%
      summarise(L = sum(L),
                K = sum(K),
                # etc
                count = n())
```

Which provides me the following output:

```
    Date         Status  sub_status   value_class G H I J K L NA Count
    2020-03-20   SA      a            0-15000     0 0 0 0 1 1 0  2
    2020-03-20   SA      b            0-15000     0 0 0 0 1 0 0  1
    ................
    ................
```

I want to get the following output using the `DF`, where the `Status` column has distinct 3 values and `Flag2` has either values or [null] or NA and finally `Flag3` column has distinct 7 values with [null] or NA. For one distinct `ID` we have multiple entry of `Flag3` column.

I Need to create the following dataframe, by creating a 3 group based on `Value` like 0-15000, 15000-50000.

- If for a distinct ID `Flag2` has some value other than 0 or [null]/NA but `Flag3` has value 0 or [null]/NA then it would be `a`.
- If for a distinct ID `Flag3` has some value other than 0 or [null]/NA but `Flag2` has value 0 or [null]/NA then it would be `b`
- If for a distinct ID both `Flag2` & `Flag3` has some value other than 0 or [Null]/NA then it would be `c`
- If for a distinct ID both `Flag2` & `Flag3` has value 0 or [Null]/NA the it would be `d`

The count will be a distinct group by `ID`. Also, for the first-row (Where the `Status` i.e SA, RE etc starts) `percentage` will get calculated by the `Total` and below the percentage for sub_status (i.e a,b,c etc) get calculated by the count of status.

I want to arrange the above mentioned datafrmae in the following structure with `percent` and `Total` column in html table format which can be attached in an email using mailR library.

I'm using the code:

```
    library(tableHTML)

    html_table<-df %>% tableHTML(rownames = FALSE,
                                      widths = rep(120, 10),
                                      caption = "XYZ (System Date)") %>%
      add_css_caption(css = list(c("font-weight", "border","font-size"),
                                 c("bold", "1px solid black","16px")))%>% 
      add_css_row(css = list(c("background-color"), c("lightblue")), rows = 0:1)%>%
      add_css_caption(css = list(c("background-color"), c("lightblue")))
```

```
    20/03/2020                 0 - 15000                         15000 - 50000
Status      count   percent  L K J H G [Null] count   percent  L K J H G [Null]   Total
SA            2      2/4     1 1 0 0 0   1      2              0 0 1 1 0    0       4
a             1      1/2     0 1 0 0 0   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       1
b             0       -      0 0 0 0 0   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       0
c             1      1/2     1 0 0 0 0   0      2              0 0 1 1 0    0       3
d             0       -      0 0 0 0 0   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       0
RE            2      2/5     0 0 0 0 1   1      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       2
a             1              0 0 0 0 1   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       1
b             1              0 0 0 0 0   1      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       1
c             0              0 0 0 0 0   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       0
d             0              0 0 0 0 0   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       0
XA            1              0 0 0 0 0   1      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       1
a             0              0 0 0 0 0   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       0
b             0              0 0 0 0 0   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       0
c             0              0 0 0 0 0   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       0
d             1              0 0 0 0 0   1      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       1
Total         5              1 1 0 0 1   3      2              0 0 1 1 0    0       7
```

I have mentioned the required output based on the latest date which is 20/03/2020, if the dataframe don't have the latest date as per `startdate` keep all the value 0 in the output dataframe. The percentage column is just for the reference there will be calculated percentage values.

Also, I want to keep the structure static. For Example, if any of the parameters are not present for a day the output structure would be the same with 0 value.

For Example, Suppose date 17/03/2020 doesn't have any row with status SA or sub_status c the place holder for that will be there in the output with value as 0.

**Note:** The desired output is just for the format perspective. The numbers might not match with `dput` df.

Comment: instead of using the R package `tableHTML`, can you use another R package, like `gt`?

Comment: what's `reps_rt`? it's not in the original `df`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean exactly, by >>> `The count will be a distinct group by ID.` you mean the ID column in your sample data? because you didn't use it in the group_by

Comment: @DS_UNI: My approach my not be correct because as you may see in sample df there are samp ids multiple time because of column `Flag3`. Though, in my output dataframe I want them to count as distinct that's why I said group by I'd.

Comment: Do you mean that the table you provided as an expected output belongs to one ID? or should we ignore the ID altogether? In your sample data the only difference between the first three rows (i.e. ID='P-1') is the Date column, which is actually a timestamp, so all three rows would be just one if we consider the Date only (and no time). Can you provide an expected output that matches the provided sample (or provide a sample that matches the output), otherwise anything

Comment: @DS_UNI: Yes, you are correct. Infact one simple solution could be wherever the `Flag3` is [null] or blank consider it 0 else consider it 1.

Comment: @DS_UNI: Did you understand, Please let me know if you can help with the possible solution.

Comment: Please could you edit the question and replace the mutate and summarise etc... part with your actual code

Comment: And how is this different from the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61145404/11355066

Comment: @Cole: I'm trying to restructure the dataframe in html itself here.

Comment: Then this question should just include the intended output of the other question. This one is confusing as is and includes 90% of the text of the other one

Comment: @Cole: ok, I didn't know that before.

Comment: @Cole: Let me know if the output is possible with R.

Comment: It is probably doable but it's hard to help. The code you have is truncated so we cannot copy and paste to try ourselves and then it appears the final output does not match the input values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211991/discussion-between-user9211845-and-cole).